# How to rewrite schema violating Unique Particle Attribution?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have written a schema that unfortunately violates Unique Particle Attribution. How can I rewrite it to make it valid?

```
<xsd:complexType name="A">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="elem" type="ex:B" minOccurs="0" />
        <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:element name="elem" type="ex:A" />
            <xsd:element name="elem" type="ex:B" minOccurs="0" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="B">
</xsd:complexType>
```

The aimed at structure is a sequence of `<elem />`s of alternating types `ex:A` and `ex:B` where `<elem />`s of type `ex:B` are optional. There may be any number of subsequent `<elem />`s of type `ex:A`, but there must not be two `<elem />`s of type `ex:B` without an `<elem />` of type `ex:A` in between them.
The schema should validate for the following examples:

Example 1:

```
<elem /> <!-- ex:B defines an empty element -->
<elem> <!-- some content according to ex:A --> </elem>
<elem />
```

Example 2:

```
<elem> <!-- some content according to ex:A --> </elem>
<elem />
<elem> <!-- some content according to ex:A --> </elem>
<elem> <!-- some content according to ex:A --> </elem>
<elem />
```

In case my intention does not become clear, please ask for clarification.

Comment: Before going down the rabbit hole... why do you call them the same (`elem`) when each is different (based on its defining type)?

Comment: @petru-gardea I consider to change the name as a last resort, but the markup is designed for use by less technically versed users and the original naming is based on something they are already accustomed to.